# The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/main-push.yml (Line: 28, Col: 9): Unrecognized function: 'hashFiles'

Tags: github, workflow

First time attempting use of hashFiles() function in GitHub workflow. Partial workflow is shown:

```
  downstream-repo-update:
    name: Update downstream repositories
    if: hashFiles('**/catalog.json')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: release
    steps:
    ...
```

The subject error is manifested in the actions results. Why is hashFiles function not found!? What me do wrong? Thx!